# Why does objdump 2.24 -S say "Address is out of bounds" for a minimal NASM object file if I add a db in a data section before the text section?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, elf, objdump

Input file:

```
section .data
    db 0
section .text
    nop
    nop
```

Commands:

```
nasm -felf32 -o main.o main.asm
objdump -S main.o
```

Output:

```
00000000 <.text>:
   0:   90                      nop
  11:   Address 0x0000000000000011 is out of bounds.
```

Why does it say: `Address 0x0000000000000011 is out of bounds.` ?

Things that work:

- `objdump -d`
- remove `.data` section
- put the `.data` section after the `.text` section
- use GAS instead with:

  ```
  .data
      .byte 0
  .text
      nop
      nop
  ```

  And:

  ```
  as --32 -o main.o main.S
  ```

  The only meaningful difference with `readelf -a` is that `nasm` sets `.text` alignment to 16 and `.data` to `4`, while GAS sets both to 1. Maybe this is the culprit?

Tested with NASM 2.10.09, Binutils 2.24, Ubuntu 14.04 AMD64.

Update: I can't reproduce when building from a recent commit `bba037e0aef1f3b17cc6cf6fd041ed6110cc375a`, so maybe this was fixed? If that is he case, all that is left is to bisect the fixing commit.

Comment: Works fine here with nasm 2.10.01, binutils 2.22, debian 7 AMD64.

Comment: @Jester thanks for trying it out. I've just reverified it and same results. A regression? Let's see if anyone else reproduces me or finds a bug report.

Comment: Managed to reproduce with 2.24, looks like a regression indeed.

Comment: git bisect says: [6a5851efac3d5b0cca704a20f3aba4abf313f526](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils.git;a=commit;h=6a5851efac3d5b0cca704a20f3aba4abf313f526) is the first bad commit

Comment: @Jester on 2.25 it seems to works fine, haven't done the bisection to find the fix though.